# Azure powershell script calculating metrics for webapps

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to find metrics for all web apps inside a subscription there are about 40 webapps. I am using get-azMetric cmdlet but due to huge number of webapps it is throwing error 'bad request' for some random webapps how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is your case. You may reach the limit of [Throttling Resource Manager requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling). This usually occurs when you use concurrent tasks.

But usually the Azure PowerShell module should take care of the 429 error itself. If you still get the same error, you may just add some retry logic in your script. And, you should use [Start-Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7) command to to wait for a while.